# File not found when running jar from command line of a NetBeans project

Tags: java, netbeans

I wrote a Java Application using NetBeans. It reads text file from the project's root directory. When I run the jar file from command line it can't find the required file.

```
String inputFile = "input.txt";
Properties prop = new Properties();
String targetFormat = null; 
try {
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream("book-info-converter.properties");
    prop.load(input);
    targetFormat = prop.getProperty("targetFormat");
}
catch(IOException ex){
     System.out.println("file not found");  
}
```

How to solve this problem? Where to put my file so that the application can find that when running jar from command line?

Comment: Have you checked your **`CLASSPATH`** settings? From which directly do you invoke the call!

Comment: Simple solution put your properties file on the same folder that contain the jar

Answer (score 1):

Place the book-info-converter.properties in the `src` folder (it's better in `resources` if you have). Then you can load it as resource stream like

```
InputStream input = YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/book-info-converter.properties");
```